# Why aren't people trying to answer my questions?

Tags: discussion, answers

I mean for my past few questions, people have been correcting my mistakes but no one offers to help. I get it I made mistakes but people just criticise my questions rather help me solve a problem. I expect better from this forrum. My questions do get upvotes but remains unanswered.

Comment: Of your most recent 8 questions, 5 have answers and 1 has a link in a comment to an answer. I'd think that's a pretty good ratio. You did ask someone for more details, but you addressed `sir`, not `@<username>`. `sir` is polite, but the `@` reference will actually notify the person that you're talking to him. Make sure you type the `@`", then the first few characters of the user name, then _click_ on the name link that pops up - I've seen many people type `@sai teja` or `@sai` which will NOT notify you. (You're receiving a notification because I'm commenting on _your_ post.)

Comment: Hi! Just to correct a common misconception; [This is not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums) and that goes some way to answering why you're not getting "comments pointing you in the right direction". Comments will help you improve your question to the point you will (hopefully) get a really good answer.

Comment: It helps if you accept answers that you are satisfied with, and/or upvote answers that you find useful.

Answer (score 2):

> Why aren't people trying to answer my questions?

Because this site actively discourages *trying*. Either a person knows the answer, and posts it, or doesn't, and no answer is posted.

You are probably asking questions that not so many people know the answer to, and thus it is more difficult for an answer to be posted.

Comment: I would appreciate it people can atleast point us in a direction via comments or tell us something to give us direction. That would be a good start and that's how we learn right. Encourage learning please everyone is not perfect. All I get is suggestions for corrections. These kind of forums should encourage people to aske questions not discourage them.

Comment: @saiteja I did not say that we discourage asking question, quite the contrary. But we discourage giving incorrect answers, and someone "trying" to answer is likely to give a wrong answer.

Comment: Ok that's absolutely right. "Someone trying is to answer is likely to give a wrong answer".
My point is why don't you atleast point us to a direction, it need not give an answer directly but certainly it will help learners like us.
Not trying to argue here, we should come up with a solution and I want to contribute to it.

Comment: @saiteja 2 things go against that: 1. I think you need to know the answer, or part of it, to direct correctly 2. we actively encourage to post answers, even partial ones, in the answer field, not the comments. This means that if no answers are posted, then it is likely that noone knowing the answer is on the site